# Get the certificate expiration date of an application using codesign on mac?

Tags: macos, certificate, codesign

I'm trying to retrieve the certificate expiration date an application using the codesign command line tool, but I cannot seem to find the date that the certificate will expire. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use codesign to extract the certificates to the current directory:

```
codesign --display --extract-certificates /Applications/Example.app
```

You can then use Quick Look to view them:

```
qlmanage -c public.x509-certificate -p codesign*
```

Comment: this was an awesome response!

Comment: Does not work now for me on Mojave, nevertheless, after extracting, and creating a temporary keychain in Keychain Access.app, and dropping the extracted cert in it, I can view what I need.

Comment: Still working in Ventura 13.4.1.

Answer (score 5):

The selected answer did not quite work for me, but a slight variation found [here](https://github.com/hewigovens/hewigovens.github.com/wiki/codesign-extract-certificates) using `openssl` did the trick. In short,

```
codesign -dvvvv --extract-certificates /Applications/Example.app

openssl x509 -inform DER -in codesign0 -text
```

Comment: This one worked. The "qlmanage" one didn't work on my system. Perhaps it's different because my workstation didn't have the certificate installed, but using openssl, I apparently didn't need that.

Comment: You should also be able to rename `codesign0` to `codesign0.crt` and preview it with the spacebar.